# Find the power series from the given maclaurin sequence

Tags: summation, power-series, taylor-expansion

I have made a post regard this particular question but was incorrect in what I was asking.
The sequence needs to be written in sigma notation, not as a summation.

The given sequence is:
$$x+2x^3+x^3+2x^4+x^5+2x^6+...$$
I can see that the sum will be an alternating series with a $(-1)^n$ term, starting at $n=1$.
After asking my professor for help, he gave me the hint that the sum will in fact have two terms added together.

What I was able to deduce from the given sequence is:
$$\sum^\infty_{n=1} 2\frac{1+(-1)^n}{2}x^n$$ 
Is my assumption correct or does my answer require work?

Comment: That won't work; if $n$ is odd, then $(-1)^n=-1$, and $1+(-1)=0$, so all the odd-indexed terms would vanish.

Comment: @user170231 Could you give me a hint as how to derive the proper sigma notation from the given.

Comment: You can do it by inspection: $\frac32-\frac12=1$ and $\frac32+\frac12=2$, so you can use $\frac32+\frac{(-1)^n}2$. (No need to multiply by $2$)

Comment: $$x+2x^3+x^3+2x^4+x^5+2x^6+... \\= \sum_{i=0}^{\infty} x^{2i+1}+\sum_{i=0}^{\infty}2x^{2i+2} \\=\sum_{i=0}^{\infty} x^{2i+1}+2x^{2i+2} \\= \sum_{i=1}^{\infty}x^i+\sum_{i=0}^{\infty}x^{2i+2}$$